Why do two computers on the same network have wildly different download speeds?
I need some help with this because I'm stumped.
I have two computers:

A gaming PC with a 2.5Gbps NIC.
An Intel NUC with a 2.5Gbps NIC.

Both of these are plugged into a 2.5Gbps Netgear unmanaged switch. All devices are using Cat 8 cables.

When I do a speed test on the gaming PC on fast.com I get 1.6Gbps down.
When I do a speed test on the NUC on fast.com I get 300Mbps down.

So what gives here? I tried swapping the Ethernet cable but that did not help.
I don't see any reason the NUC should be so slow and I'm not sure how to fix this. Any suggestions?

Did they both negotiate 2.5Gbps mode? (i.e. what does the OS show, and what does the switch show for each port?) Are they both connecting to the same server via the same address? (some ISPs have really bad IPv6 routing) Have you tried testing the connection between the two computers, not involving the Internet at all (or your router for that matter)? Do they both show the same CPU load when being tested (including things like hardware interrupts)?

Both PCs negotiate at 2.5Gbps mode as confirmed in the network adapter status screen. Both PCs have IPv6 turned off. The CPU load on the NUC during a speedtest never goes over 30%. I just tested the connection between the two with iPerf and Im getting 2.5Gbps between the two, so the full link speed.

Can you run iperf3 between devices on the local network to identify a difference? (even a 1Gb/s host could be useful for identifying issues with the NUC)

I just tried this and between the two PCs Im getting 2.5Gbps, so the full link speed

So you did! Good timing :) ... did you run in both directions? (-R)

I swapped the server/client which should be good enough right? Both directions is 2.5Gbps

I've also made sure that all of my drivers are up to date and I have the latest windows updates

According to these figures, the problem is not with the computers or the switch. Can you test with another website, for example https://www.speedtest.net/?

Are any of the ethernet cables between the devices and the switch, the switch and the router, and the router and the modem over 100m in length?

No all the cables are 6ft cables. I tried with multiple speedtest websites and they're all pretty much the same. On the gaming PC I get full download speeds. On the NUC I get 300-500Mbps depending on which site Im using.

I did some research on the 1225-v which is the ethernet controller my NUC has. It seems a lot of people have had issues with slow download speeds. I tried removing and reinstalling the NIC drivers and that didn't help. At this point I might just buy a 2.5Gbps USB NIC and call it a day because this is getting nuts. Im pretty adept at networking in general and this has me stumped, so Im leaning towards this being Intels fault.

Have you tried your NUC under a different OS like a live Linux distro?

I bought a USB-C 2.5Gbps Ethernet adapter and that plugged into the NUC gets full expected download speeds.
Chalking this up to a hardware issue caused by Intel and the awful I225-V network controller.
